# Why the Vector3.Dot value is -12 when running the game?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string currentMode;

    private Transform player;
    private InteractableMode currentInteractableMode;
    private string currentDesription;
    private float originDistance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;

        originDistance = transform.GetComponent<InteractableItem>().distance;
    }

    public enum InteractableMode
    {
        Description,
        Action,
        ActionWithoutThrow
    };

    public enum ViewMode
    {
        FrontView,
        AllView
    };

    public ViewMode viewMode = ViewMode.AllView;

    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Description;
    public float distance;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";

    public bool IsAnyAction()
    {
        return interactableMode == InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow || interactableMode == InteractableMode.Action;
    }

    public bool IsActionWithoutThrow()
    {
        return interactableMode == InteractableMode.ActionWithoutThrow;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        currentMode = GetComponent<InteractableItem>().interactableMode.ToString();
        currentInteractableMode = GetComponent<InteractableItem>().interactableMode;
        currentDesription = GetComponent<InteractableItem>().description;
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var heading = transform.position - player.transform.position;
        var dot = Vector3.Dot(heading, -transform.forward);

        if(viewMode == ViewMode.FrontView
            && dot < 1)
        {
            transform.GetComponent<InteractableItem>().distance = 0;
        }

        if (viewMode == ViewMode.FrontView
            && dot > 1)
        {
            transform.GetComponent<InteractableItem>().distance = originDistance;
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to some objects and one of them the ViewMode is set to FrontView and then when running the game first time the dot value is -12 and then it's getting inside and going the line :

```
if(viewMode == ViewMode.FrontView
    && dot < 1)
{
    transform.GetComponent<InteractableItem>().distance = 0;
}
```

but it should not set the distance to 0.  only if I'm getting close enough to the item then it should see the item from the front and then only if I'm moving the player behind the item the dot should be minus and set the distance to 0 but for some reason the dot is minus 12 when running the game so it's setting the distance to 0 right away.

Comment: Would a Vector3.Distance not be a better use case for this?

Comment: @Zibelas I'm not sure. How Vector3.Distance will detect if the player is behind the item or in front ?

Comment: Why do you keep using `GetComponent` over and over to get a reference to what might very well just be `this`?

Comment: @DMGregory Right I changed it and get reference only once in the Start.

Comment: Why get the reference this way at all? Are you sure you don't just want to refer to `this` component? It's very strange to search your own game object for an instance of your own type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns a negative value if the player is behind the item. This is easy to verify with a simple test script:

```
public class DotTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public float dot;

    private void Start() {
        Assert.IsNotNull(target);
    }

    private void Update() {
        var heading = transform.position - target.transform.position;
        dot = Vector3.Dot(heading, -transform.forward);
    }
}
```

Just move the object with this script around and watch the value of the `dot` field in the Inspector.

`Vector3.Dot()` returns a positive value if two vectors are facing the same direction, and a negative value if they're facing opposite directions. You're comparing the direction *from the player to the item* to the item's backward vector.

[image: Diagram]

If you don't want the code to return a negative value in this situation, you need to change the code (just get rid of the minus sign before `transform.forward`). If you think this same code is working correctly in other places and not here, you are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product returns -12 because you're facing away from the object initially.

You should use

```
var heading = player.transform.position - transform.position;
var dot = Vector3.Dot(heading.normalized, transform.forward);
```

to figure out if you're facing the object. And heading must be normalized for the dot product.

If dot is greater than 0 then you're facing the object (might want a higher threshold, such as Mathf.Cos(45 * Mathf.Deg2Rad) for looking at it up to 45 degrees)

And use `heading.magnitude` to find the distance.

Also, by flipping around `transform.position - player.transform.position` you avoid the negative operator on the Vector3.

Comment: In most of the objects with the script attached it's working fine.  but no matter I tried to change so far for one object it's not working.  For some reason when I'm running the game this specific object the dot is minus and the distance is set to 0.  Could be the problem is that the object too small ? It's working with other objects.

Comment: His example code is for the item, not the player. It returns a negative value if the player is behind the item. The player's heading is not relevant in his equation.